# matching exact part of expression

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to match strings that are like this:

"something-test() something more"

I'm using the expression:

> grep("test()", text, value=TRUE)

But this is also matching:

"something-test something() more"

I want it to match only **test()** when () is immediately following test. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you need to escape your parenthisis..  `grep("test\(\)", text, value=TRUE)`

Comment: Maybe argument "fixed" set to `TRUE` could be helpful, too?

Comment: I tried that, didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should escape the parenthesis

```
grep( "\\btest\\(\\)" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the parenthesis:

```
grep("test\(\)", text, value=TRUE)
```

Parenthesis have special meaning in a regex, they say that we want to capture what's matched.

Answer (score 1):

Escape parens:

```
text <- c("something-test() something more", "something-test something() more")
grep("test\\(\\)", text, value=TRUE)
# [1] "something-test() something more"
```